# Magento Admin Login Error

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

Please Help. Have been stuck for days.

I've been trying to connect to **Magento Admin**. The website itself is working fine. I've tried logging in and each time I'd get this message:

*Network Error (tcp_error) 
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
For assistance, contact your network support team.*

I've tried the following:

1. Deleted all the files inside /var/cache folder.
2. Sudo reboot
3. I read that I need to also delete maintenance.flag file in my root folder. I can't find this file anywhere.

Please help.

Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: You have something bad on the server, too much traffic and/or looping code, hard to give you an answer, check what the server is doing.

Comment: it appears like your server is down. You can cross-check by accessing other websites on the same server.